# Fancybox v2 failing on second click

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, overlay

I have a site that uses the ajax option of Fancybox v2 to display certain bits of information such as the help, contact information, etc. I have noticed a problem with it, however, where it works fine on the first click but generally misbehaves on subsequent clicks - the actual pop-up window may appear briefly and then disappear, or it may never appear at all, and the overlay may load two or three times so that it takes several clicks to clear it.

It doesn't matter whether you click the same link or another link that also uses Fancybox. The Firebug console reports no errors. If you refresh the page you get another single reliable click, and then subsequent clicks exhibit the odd behaviour again.

I have created a stripped-down version of one of our pages (removing all other scripts) to see if there was something causing a conflict, but this doesn't seem to be the case. You can have a look at it here:

http://frontandback.com.au/fancytest/

The three links in the top-right of the site have the Fancybox applied to them. Example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" data-fancybox-href="index.html #main" target="_blank" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" data-fancybox-href="index.html #main" target="_blank" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" data-fancybox-href="index.html #main" target="_blank" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax">FAQs</a></li>
</ul>
```

If anyone has any suggestions as to what is causing this odd problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: For each of your three links, I think it's a whitespace issue on HASHTAG? Can you test and change `data-fancybox-href="index.html #main"` to `data-fancybox-href="index.html#main"`. That same issue is here: `href="legals.aspx #main"`

Comment: you are trying to load the same page from within you are loading fancybox so it goes into a loop trying to reload jQuery and fancybox scripts (check your console) ... try loading a separated page instead.... or if the content is inside the same page, use type : `inline` instead of ajax

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. A few further comments:

@JFK: That was just for the purpose of this example. The real site (which is currently behind our company firewall so I can't point people at it) has the links going to different pages and the same error happens. However there may be merit to the idea that it's because the pages linked to also have the scripts on them. Not sure what would be a way around this, though.

Comment: @Seona : if those pages have their own scripts and you want them to behave as independent pages, load them in `iframe` mode so instead of using `class="fancybox fancybox.ajax"` use `class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"`, otherwise those pages will try to merge with the main page hence possible conflicts.

Comment: @arttronics: The hashtag with the space before it is the way that the system seems to work if you want to display only part of the page. I can't now find where I got that information, but if I remove the space as you suggest, it loads the entire page rather than just the main content panel (so the box contains all of the navigation, header and footer, etc). Either way, the problem still occurs.

Comment: @arttronics: I've also had a look at the three errors in the validation tool. One is a stray bit of ASP.NET code that I failed to excise from the code I copied across into this example. Once is a badly formed link (but since the error is occurring on links that don't have this problem, I don't think it's related) and the meta one confuses me because it's code that I got from the HTML5 Boilerplate and as such would have assumed is correct. I'll look into it.

Comment: @JFK: Ah, progress. So I switched to iframe instead of ajax. Now it seems to work a lot more consistently. Unfortunately, the ability to limit the display to only part of the page (which from memory was why I was using the ajax option in the first place) no longer works - If I keep the space before the hashtag, I get a "page not found" and if I remove it I just get the whole page.

I shall keep digging, however. Thanks for your advice. :)

Comment: So I found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054673/jquery-fancybox-target-specific-div-id-in-iframe). It suggests that the only way to do what I'm wanting is to use the ajax option, but we've established that this won't work for me. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: @Seona : you may find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/13620584/1055987 ... just pass the ref using `href` rather than `data-fancybox-href` like `href="externalPage.html#main"`

Comment: @JFK: You're a legend! That worked beautifully. I'll start rolling this back into the real site now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620584/1055987)** I created a revised version where you can load partial content from a file via ajax.

This new revision uses a (HTML5) `data-` attribute to pass the `hash` of the URL so instead of doing this

```
<li><a href="index.html" data-fancybox-href="index.html #contact" target="_blank" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax">Contact us</a></li>
```

we'll do this

```
<li><a href="index.html" data-segment="#contact" target="_blank" class="fancybox">Contact us</a></li>
```

... **notice** that we are not using any special fancybox *class* `fancybox.ajax` nor `fancybox.iframe` as suggested in the comments section.

Then the basic script

```
$(".fancybox").on("click", function() {
    targetContent = $("<div />").load(this.href +" "+ $(this).data("segment")); 
    $.fancybox(targetContent, {
        fitToView: false,
        autoSize : false,
        width: 420, // or whatever
        height: 280
    }); // fancybox
    return false; // prevent default
}); // on
```

You may set dimensions to each `<div>` from the remote file via `style=""` attribute, then set `autoSize : true` and remove the `width` and `height` options to get a dynamic size.

Of course, the **[revised DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/loadPartialContentRevised_17dec12.html)**

Comment: Awesome, thanks @JFK. Sadly, I don't have the reputation to upvote this yet. But you rock. :D